# OVP cards can't load data in Fiori site

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I created OVP application to display different cards. This application works well when I deploy it to my Fiori Launchpad page. 
[OVP cards work well in Fiori launchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9519U.jpg)

But the content of OVP application cannot be loaded when I add it to my Site
[same OVP cards cannot be loaded in Portal site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM0mb.jpg)

It is so weird that OVP application works differently by deploying them to Fiori launchpad and Portal site. Can anyone help me out of this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is any error in the console? Something like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

If your Portal has a different domain that your OData service you will get a CORS issue.

The typical scenario is:

1.- Your OData comes from an ABAP system

2.- Your portal is in a JAVA system

One possible solution. Set a WebDispacher in front of them and access the Portal through the WD. The WD will redirect your requests to the corresponsing system, but your browser will receive everything from the WD domain, so no CORS...

Comment: Thank you for answering! There is no CORS error from console. But with error "Could not load annotation URL ...".
I used local annotation xml file and it works well on Fiori Launchpad, but doesn't on Portal site. Don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved because the OVP cards works in Fiori launchpad ONLY.
https://jam4.sapjam.com/questions/9NKsSwCxyTD91wIX7CIZig

Comment: Another option to solve it by changing the application type to enable "SAPUI5 Client Build".